# wordpress site - http 500 error after editing php file

Tags: css, wordpress, ftp, admin

I'm not really familiar with CSS coding and stuff. And I was fiddling around with the php file on WordPress editor admin. Now the website is down and showing an HTTP 500 error.

I've tried to restore the original lines of code through FTP, but it's still not working.

Comment: Could you explain the act of "fiddling" a bit more and also with which php file, is it `wp-admin.php`?

Comment: I think you should restart your webserver. In some cases, PHP cached your PHP codes.

Comment: The code, screenshot of the error page, etc. we need those to answer your question

Comment: Your question is more of a system administration question, not a coding question -- and so it probably belongs on the ServerFault site.  Also your question amounts to "I broke it and have no idea what to do. Help me!"  We can't help you without a lot more information.  The sorts of things you need to do involve looking at the log files in /var/log while hitting your site with your browser to generate some 500 errors in the log.  The exact error message would be in the log files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know your WordPress version. If not, you can check it from the readme.html file. Download your WordPress version package from this [here](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) and replace only the wp-admin and wp-includes folders manually from it to your failed WordPress installation.

Comment: That's the exact answer! I checked it by myself!

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, and could be simply posted as a comment.